show that the number of distint orbit is equal to times of unit representation
Let $X$ be a finite set on which $G$ acts, let $p$ be the corresponding permutation
representation, and let $\chi$ be its character.
The set $O_x$ of images under $G$ of an element $x \in X$ is called an orbit.
Let $c$ be the number of distinct orbits. Show that $c$ is equal to the number of times that $p$ contains the unit representation $I$
Here is the proof what I am going, but I face some stuck about computing the unit representation.
pf:
Let $W$ denote the permutation representation and let ${e_x}_{x\in X}$ be its basis. Let $x\in X $ and consider the space $X_y$ spanned by the vector $y = \sum_{z \in Gx} e_z$.Then $\rho_s y $ = $\sum_{z \in Gx} \rho_s e_z = \sum_{z \in Gx} e_{sz}$ which is just a re-ordering of $y$, so $\rho_s y = y$ for all$ s \in G $. Hence, $X_y $ is invariant under the action of $G $, so $X_y$ is a subrepresentation of $W $ isomorphic to the trivial representation. Since our choice of $x$  was arbitrary, we see that we can obtain such a copy of the trivial representation for each of the $c$ orbits of $X $.
The following make me confuse.
"Since no other subspace of $ W $ is fixed by the action of $G $", we see that $c$ is precisely the number of copies of the trivial representation in $ \rho$.
my question:, I also set p equal to sum of each y( taken from each conjugacy class, then this p is also invariant in the action of G. can someone help me? thanks in advanced.

The statement is equivalent to "Burnside's lemma" (sometimes called Cauchy-Frobenius lemma). You only need the definition of the permuation character.
